# How can I add validation for input length of a string?

Tags: python, validation

I am currently testing my knowledge of python programming as a student and can't get Len() to work on a simple program that asks a user for a user name that is maximum 12 letters long

```
Name = input("What Is Your Player Name\t")
# Check That The User Has Got A Maximun Of 12 Characters
if Name.len(0-13):

else:
    print("Your Name Can Only Contain 12 Characters")
```

Comment: There is not `len()` string function, there is `__len__` which should be used as `len(Name)`. There is also no statement if first condition is True, so your code won't work.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you read the documentation; it's not clear why you thought a string had a `len` method, or why it would return a boolean, or why `0-13` would be interpreted as a valid range (rather than `-13`). Just guessing isn't an effective means of learning the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In extension of the other answers using [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) you might want to look into using a [while-loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) to ask the user to enter the name again if it is more than 12 characters like so:

```
while(True):
  name = input("What is your Player Name: ")
  if len(name) > 12:
     print("Your Player Name can only contain a maximum of 12 characters")
  else:
    break;

print("\nYou entered the Player Name: %s" % name)
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FKmY/0)

Comment: Personally, I would suggest not providing complete solutions to homework questions, especially without an explanation as to why your solution is better than the one they provided. This becomes increasingly important the newer to programming the asker is, as they will then ask follow on questions with the same root misunderstanding.

Comment: I get you point here is some explanation of my answer: I provided a link to the pydoc for `len()` since @OP should learn how to use it for their own benefit in the future. I changed the variable `Name` to `name` since variables in python in most cases should use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). I changed the print statement to more accurately reflect what the `if-statement` was actually testing. And lastly I added a `while-loop`which usually is the natural continuation for these type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you pass the String into the len function to return the length of the String.

```
len(Name)
```